# How many bits in the Apple Logo?

Tags: computer-puzzle, computer-science, humor

Sorry in advance if this is a bit easy or if it breaks any rules, but it's the best I can think of.

The Question:

> If there are 16 bits in a picture of an apple, how many bits in the Apple Logo?

Comment: Was the pun "a bit easy", intended? :P

Comment: This is really just a pun/joke, more than an actual puzzle (imho).

Comment: Given that you do need to solve something, by making both a word association and an image association to get the joke, I'd vote that it _is_ a puzzle.  Perhaps an easy one, but still a puzzle, and it's not something that everyone would get immediately.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> 8

Because...

> Apple Logo has 1 bite taken.

Comment: *facepalmtree* ;-;

Answer (score 22):

I'm pretty sure WeShall has it, but I'd like to point out that it might be as high as

> 12

if we assume that

> the amount taken out of the logo is just a [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

Comment: Good One. Like it. :)

Comment: Lol! Didn't think of it that way.

Comment: made me laugh. worth an upvote.